# Union and result_array in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, codeigniter

need some advices how to use correctly union and result_array. I Have tables with different row, but I must to do union, because them must be printed in same table row.

So than no union my function looking like this:

```
function get_all() {
    $this->db->select('id, pavadinimas, prekesid, linkas');
    $query = $this->db->get('parduotuve');
    return $query->result_array();
```

With union

```
 function get_all() {

    $this->db->select('id, pavadinimas, prekesid, linkas');
    $this->db->from('parduotuve');
    $query1=$this->db->get()->result();

    $this->db->select('kpavadinimas');
    $this->db->from('kategorija');
    $query2=$this->db->get()->result();



    return $query->result_array=array_merge($query1, $query2);
```

but now I have error

```
 Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

in this view lines:

```
 foreach ($products as $product){
                    $product_id = $product['id'];
```

Any ideas how to fix it and make good union?

edit1.

```
array(4) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#20 (4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["pavadinimas"]=>  string(8) "varle.lt" ["prekesid"]=> string(22) "div[@itemprop="price"]" ["linkas"]=>  string(15) "http://varle.lt" }
 [1]=> object(stdClass)#21 (4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["pavadinimas"]=> string(7) "pigu.lt" ["prekesid"]=> string(38) "div[id="price_block"] strong#sellPrice" ["linkas"]=>   string(14) "http://pigu.lt" }
  [2]=> object(stdClass)#22 (4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "3" ["pavadinimas"]=> string(10) "avitela.lt" ["prekesid"]=> string(9) "sadasdasd" ["linkas"]=> string(6) "asdasd" }
 [3]=> object(stdClass)#23 (4) { ["id"]=> string(2) "50" ["pavadinimas"]=> string(4) "dddd" ["prekesid"]=> string(4) "dddd" ["linkas"]=> string(3) "ddd" } }
```

edit2:

now I got this:

```
   Error Number: 1096

  No tables used

 SELECT *

 Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\svetaine\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

and function

```
   function get_all() {
   $this->db->select('id, pavadinimas, prekesid, linkas');
  $this->db->from('parduotuve');
   $this->db->get()->result_array();;
$query1=$this->db->get()->result();

 $this->db->select('kpavadinimas');
 $this->db->from('kategorija');
 $this->db->get()->result_array();
$query2=$this->db->get()->result();

 return array_merge($query1, $query2);

}
```

Comment: Select using JOIN, and you wont need any unions. And by the way, you can't use array_merge on objects. What var_dump($query1) returns?

Comment: edited with your question

Comment: `$product_id = $product['id'];` should be `$product_id = $product->id;` unless you change the `$this->db->get()->result();` to `$this->db->get()->result_array();` that will get rid of ur php errors

Comment: What results do you expect? 
You don't need ```return $query->result_array=array_merge($query1, $query2);``` Just do ```return array_merge($query1, $query2);``` and apply mic comment.

Comment: updated. I need create table with elements from different tables. from table I must edit table row or create new